# ArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange is not working correctly

Tags: android, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

I want to control the display of my ListView data. I am filtering and sorting before I want to display the list. The list is being refreshed before I call publishResults() as well as after I do my filtering and call publishResults().

```
public StoreAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Store> items, StoresTab storeTab) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.storeTab = storeTab;
    this.context = context;
    this.filter = new StoreFilter();
    imageLoader = ImageThreadLoader.getOnDiskInstance(context);
    setNotifyOnChange(false);
}

protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // NOTE: this function is *always* called from the UI thread.
        ArrayList<Store> filtered = (ArrayList<Store>)results.values;
        clear();
        if (filtered != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filtered.size(); i++)
            {
                add(filtered.get(i));
            }
            sort(storeTab);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The view is displayed before I call the filter operation. I call adater.add() method inside my ListActivity and do not call notifyDataSetChanged() anywhere else.

I'm spinning my wheels here. I do not have the source to debug it.

When I debug I can see the notifydatasetchanged property=false when the arrayAdapter.getView is called. Is there a way to find out what event is calling this to be called?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() instead of notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Its getting notified. The problem is that it is getting notified before I have called the notifyDataSetChanged(). My view is generated twice, once before notifyDataSetChanged is called and once after.

Comment: So your saying that it is notifying the list before the second view is generated?  Maybe add some booleans to make sure it does not happen. ALso I like add some logs in the database to fins the order of procedure and then debug from there.

Comment: It is notifying the list to draw before I call the notifyDataSetChanged. Ive got some booleans and now it is not drawing but its still not behaving to spec. I'm not going to spend too much time on this as I have a workaround. Thanks Jared.